# iOS Swift: Set corner radius according to button height

Tags: ios, swift

`frame.height` returns the correct value but the corner radius doesn't change.

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
```

Comment: I was missing `clipsToBounds = true`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
clipsToBounds = true
```

Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`btnOK = UIButton`
By default UIButton was square, so set corner radius was better then default UI.

**Swift 4**

```
    btnOK.layer.cornerRadius = btnOK.bounds.height/2
```